# PostgreSQL 9.0.1 Multiple Clusters and Shared Buffers Settings in Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: configuration, windows-server-2008-r2, postgresql

According to the PostgreSQL documentation, "The useful range for shared_buffers on Windows systems is generally from 64MB to 512MB.".

I'm wondering how this might alter when running multiple database clusters (in PostgreSQL parlance) on a single server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numbers don't change.  There is a separate shared buffer pool per cluster.